# How to get jsonarry value from json response

Tags: android, json

am getting json response like this

> {"content": "", "breadcrumb": "", "subtitle": "", "author": "",
>   "title": "fas", "absolute_url":
>   "http://abrilemlondres.com.br/599/voce-em-londres/fas",
>   "commentsEnabled": false, "releaseDateTime": 1335524514, "image":
>   ["http://abrilemlondres.com.br/m/up/40/00/553.jpg"], "tags": "ff"}

and how to get image value from this response......

Answer (score 2):

The below code snippet gives you the desired value.

```
String jsonExample = "{\"content\": \"\", \"breadcrumb\": \"\", \"subtitle\": \"\",                \"author\": \"\", \"title\": \"fas\", \"absolute_url\": \"http://abrilemlondres.com.br/599/voce-em-londres/fas\", \"commentsEnabled\": false, \"releaseDateTime\": 1335524514, \"image\": [\"http://abrilemlondres.com.br/m/up/40/00/553.jpg\"], \"tags\": \"ff\"}";

JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject(jsonExample);

JSONArray array = jsonobject.getJSONArray("image");

System.out.println("$$$$$$$$$      "+array.getString(0)+"&&&&&&&&     " );
```